# How to change the arrow-head size in `feynmp`

Tags: arrows, feynmp, feynmp-auto

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1cm}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i1,v4}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o2,v2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i2,v3}
    \fmf{dbl_plain_arrow}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,v4,v3}
    \fmfdotn{v}{4}  
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output
[image]

How can I change the size of the double-lined arrow-head to have the same size as the arrow-head of the single-line? I've looked into the [documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) and in table 3 there is an option listed as `decoration.size`, but I can't figure out how to use it correctly.. If I exchange the line in the code that produces the double-lined arrow with

```
\fmf{dbl_plain_arrow,decoration.size=2cm}{v3,v2,v1}
```

nothing changes..

Appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FeynMF manual describes something similar in section 2.8 (Raw metafont). In particular, it shows how to draw a line with an enlarged arrow. Here we just need the opposite `:-)`

The standard line styles are defined in the file `feynmp.mp`, which is the first thing passed to your `.mp` file when you issue `\begin{fmffile}{...}`. In `feynmp.mp` we find

```
style_def dbl_plain_arrow expr p =
  draw_double_arrow p;
enddef;
```

so basically `dbl_plain_arrow` is an alias for `double_arrow`, which in turn is defined as

```
style_def double_arrow expr p =
  draw_double p;
  shrink (1.5);
    cfill (arrow p);
  endshrink;
enddef;
```

The `shrink` bit is what makes the arrow look larger (because of the factor `1.5`). You can then overwrite this definition and use a normal arrow

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\fmfcmd{%
 style_def double_arrow expr p =
  draw_double p;
  cfill (arrow p);
 enddef;
}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1cm}%
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i1,v4}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o2,v2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i2,v3}
    \fmf{dbl_plain_arrow}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,v4,v3}
    \fmfdotn{v}{4}  
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could redefine only `dbl_plain_arrow`, such that you can still have the original behaviour with `double_arrow`.

Comment: It is fantastic. How do you find the `style_def dbl_plain_arrow expr p =
  draw_double_arrow p;
enddef;` and `style_def double_arrow expr p =
  draw_double p;
  shrink (1.5);
    cfill (arrow p);
  endshrink;
enddef;`?

Comment: @Sebastiano I opened `feynmp.mp` and searched for `dbl_plain_arrow`.

Comment: But do you have a software to open feynmp.mp? I not remember this.

Comment: @Sebastiano `feynmp.mp` is just a text file, you need no software to open it other than any text editor.

Answer (score 3):

I have done several compilations and changes after I have looked at the documentation...and with a lot of humility I think that it is not possible. In fact I have thought to put, for the same cicle `v3`, `v2`, `v1` both `\fmf{dbl_plain}{v3,v2,v1}` (double line) and     `\fmf{phantom_arrow}{v3,v2,v1}`. The proof of my hypothesis it that if you prove this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1cm}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i1,v4}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o2,v2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i2,v3}
    \fmf{dbl_plain}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{phantom_arrow}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,v4,v3}
    \fmfdotn{v}{4}  
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

you have a strange output:

[image]

where you have not a rectangle. Hence the correct code is only, `dbl_plain_arrow` with the big arrow.

**Follow-up 2021/07/14**: Based on the suggestion/comment of the very nice user @campa using `tension=0` into the row

```
\fmf{phantom_arrow,tension=0}{v3,v2,v1}
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1cm}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i1,v4}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{o2,v2}
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2}{i2,v3}
    \fmf{dbl_plain}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{phantom_arrow,tension=0}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmf{fermion}{v1,v4,v3}
    \fmfdotn{v}{4}  
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't answer you on MSE: my account has been suspended for14 days, because I dared give hints for questions they declared ‘low quality’.

Comment: @Bernard No comment. I'm sorry but to suspend on these occasions seems to me pure folly. :-(

Comment: The idea is good. You can get a rectangle by drawing the phantom line with zero tension: `\fmf{phantom_arrow,tension=0}{v3,v2,v1}`. Or you can draw the rectangle first, issue `\fmffreeze`, and add the arrows afterwards.

Comment: @campa It is great for me to know English well but I am not able to. I didn't think and didn't see that there was a command like \tikzcdset also for feynmp called \fmfset (I saw the manual on page 31). Now I'm trying.

Comment: @campa Done! :-)))) What are the rules of tension=0 and \fmffreeze? If I not see an example I often misunderstand. :-(

Comment: You declare your vertices, and draw all the lines, and then imagine the lines are springs which try to contract. The "equilibrium position" determines the final form of the diagram. `tension=0` means that the line is drawn but it doesn't "pull". `\fmffreeze` can be used to freeze the vertices in the current configuration, such that drawing additional lines doesn't move them.