# Empty or not-compilable diagram using feynmf/feynmp package

Tags: compilation-error, miktex2.9, feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

Strangely today I wanted to create a graph with `feynmf`/`feynmp` package but taking for example the @egreg's answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181427/feynman-diagrams-with-feynmf-and-feynmp) I not see nothing (I compile with TeXworks).

> **Does this anomaly happen only to me?**

### First code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}% choose something better!
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

### Second code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}% choose something better!
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

I have compiled easily and I saw the graphs: see my recent answer: [How to change the arrow-head size in `feynmp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604882/how-to-change-the-arrow-head-size-in-feynmp/604894#604894) (last edit 2021/07/14). Also with my code I not see nothing.

If I use this MWE:

### Third code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmf}%%%% using this package instead of feynmp-auto or feynmp%

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{afilename}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

it is the same but I have this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.7 32-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/utente/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/feynmf\feynmf.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def)Running miktex-makemf.exe...


Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `afilena.cfg'



hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)




Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

No file Test3.aux.

feynmf: Files afilename.mf and afilename.tfm not found:
feynmf: This job will create afilename.mf, process it later with METAFONT
feynmf: and then reprocess this file. Don't worry about a harmless premature
feynmf: MakeTeXTFM that might have failed just a moment ago!
[1{C:/Users/utente/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(Test3.aux) )<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on Test3.pdf (1 page, 14615 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Test3.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Test3.log.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

Opening `miktex-makemf`:

```
2021-07-26 13:51:36,873+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (5320) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose diagram
2021-07-26 13:51:36,904+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The diagram source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:51:36,904+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The diagram source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:51:36,904+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 13:51:36,904+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 13:51:36,904+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 13:51:36,935+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (5320) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 13:52:18,624+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4544) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose diagram
2021-07-26 13:52:18,655+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The diagram source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:52:18,655+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The diagram source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:52:18,655+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 13:52:18,655+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 13:52:18,655+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 13:52:18,686+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4544) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 13:58:22,388+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4120) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose afilename
2021-07-26 13:58:22,420+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The afilename source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:58:22,420+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The afilename source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:58:22,420+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 13:58:22,420+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 13:58:22,420+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 13:58:22,451+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4120) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 13:59:19,568+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4892) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose mygraph
2021-07-26 13:59:19,615+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:59:19,615+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 13:59:19,615+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 13:59:19,615+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 13:59:19,615+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 13:59:19,646+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (4892) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 14:00:04,917+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (5616) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose mygraph
2021-07-26 14:00:04,948+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:00:04,948+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:00:04,948+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 14:00:04,948+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 14:00:04,948+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 14:00:04,979+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (5616) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 14:01:53,748+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (668) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose mygraph
2021-07-26 14:01:53,763+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:01:53,795+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The mygraph source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:01:53,795+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 14:01:53,795+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 14:01:53,795+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 14:01:53,857+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (668) finishes with exit code 1
2021-07-26 14:13:52,195+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (2588) started by 'miktex-maketfm' with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose afilename
2021-07-26 14:13:52,211+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The afilename source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:13:52,211+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The afilename source file could not be found.
2021-07-26 14:13:52,211+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Info: 
2021-07-26 14:13:52,211+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Source: 
2021-07-26 14:13:52,211+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0
2021-07-26 14:13:52,242+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (2588) finishes with exit code 1
```

This is the `.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.7 32-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.7.26)  26 JUL 2021 14:13
entering extended mode
**"C:/Users/utente/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex"
(C:/Users/utente/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/feynmf\feynmf.sty
Package: feynmf 1996/12/02 v1.08 LaTeX/Metafont Feynman Diagram Package (ohl)
\@outfmf=\write3
\fmfbuf@=\toks16
\c@fmfgraph=\count190
\grep@infile=\read2
\grep@outfile=\write4
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count191
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
No file Test3.aux.
\openout1 = `Test3.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

! Font \f@ynmf:afilename=afilename not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \@interactionmode 
l.6 \begin{fmffile}{afilename}
                              
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.


feynmf: Files afilename.mf and afilename.tfm not found:
feynmf: This job will create afilename.mf, process it later with METAFONT
feynmf: and then reprocess this file. Don't worry about a harmless premature
feynmf: MakeTeXTFM that might have failed just a moment ago!
\openout3 = `afilename.mf'.

[1

{C:/Users/utente/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(Test3.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 560 strings out of 478832
 8840 string characters out of 2855361
 302483 words of memory out of 3000000
 18569 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403730 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,5n,41p,237b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on Test3.pdf (1 page, 14615 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

> What has happened? I do not understand the reason.

Using [Papeeria](https://www.papeeria.com/) all the codes work correctly:

[image]

Comment: There have been a few changes during the years and `feynmp-auto` seems to need `-shell-escape`. It's in the list for a revision.

Answer (score 1):

I have set my editor `TeXworks` going on *Preferences* (you can see the yellow rectangle put in the top).

[image]

After I have clicked on `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` (you can see the green rectangle) and I have added, on configuration tool (to see the orange rectangle),

[image]

the line,

```
--tex-option=--shell-escape
```

and I see the graph, for example of my question here: [How to change the arrow-head size in `feynmp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604882/how-to-change-the-arrow-head-size-in-feynmp/604894#604894)

[image]